# Text editing files on a remote Raspberry Pi using local editor

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, sshfs

I am currently required to connect to my university's system of password protected rasberry pi's where I have to edit files to complete weekly projects. I am very sick of using vim in order to edit these files and tried sshfs and rmate, but have not been able to get either of these to work properly. I simply want to edit the files on the rasberry pi system with something like Sublime instead of vim.

Also, I am using MacOSX if that matters at all for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Cyberduck lets you set any application you want as an editor, so you can set Sublime as the editor that way. That's the only way I've found that works in modern macOS. Downside is I don't think you can "edit" a directory this way, if that's what you were trying to do.

There's also the paid (w/ free trial available) app Mountain Duck for mounting SSH directories like SSHFS used to do. It seems fine except that it can't follow symbolic links.

Comment: The professor told me that I can use x2go and then connect to the server through there and edit the files while I am on the same system.He also said "You do not have to run the editor on the same system you are running the program on so long as they use the same file system." He did not elaborate on how to do this and I thought maybe you would know how to do this.

Comment: @TylerLawson Haven't heard of x2go, but it looks similar to the XQuartz I'm used to. That forwards Linux GUI applications that use the X11 window system to some local client on your Mac, like screen sharing but sending some kind of rendering instructions instead of pixels. So you use a GUI editor on the remote host with it. Chances are it's going to be slow, though. I've always in this situation and have opted for getting used to Vim instead. Pairs nicely with `screen` so I can just leave editing screens open on a server and connect from my laptop whenever I want.

Comment: @TylerLawson The thing about the filesystem: He's saying you can edit the program from a separate machine as long as it shares files with the one running the program, maybe over NFS. I don't know if this helps with your use case.